# How to measure IO time in Spark over S3

Tags: performance, apache-spark, amazon-s3, hdfs

How can I tell IO durations for a Spark application doing R/W from S3 (using S3 as a filesystem sc.textFile("s3a://...")?
I would like to know the % of time doing IO of the overall app execution time.

Answer (score -2):

As I mentioned on the mailing list: not really, no.